# Is it possible to use custom manually created tables as entities in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an existing database with 40 tables. It contains relationships, keys, triggers, views, stored procedures, etc.

I'm now looking into a way to integrate dynamics crm in the process.

Question: Is it possible to create custom workflows / entities from existing database? I can copy those tables to dynamics CRM database, but I haven't found anything in the documentation. We cannot significantly change schema of our current database at this point since it is used by different services and external scripts and background tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do such a thing. CRM has its own tables and relations. One thing that I can think of is import this data to CRM using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328321.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) mechanisms and then register plugins/workflows that will create/update/delete data in your tables.